# Java - Eclipe IDE error - Error occurred during initialization of boot layer

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse for the first time, I just finished installing it, I typed the code below as instructed by my online course:

```
System.out.println("Hello World");
```

and I got the error below :

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Error reading module: C:\Users\seljouki\eclipse-workspace\MyFirstProject\bin
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: MyClass.class found in top-level directory (unnamed package not allowed in module)

Comment: Looks like you have a `module-info.java` making this a 'modular' project which doesn't match what your course wants. Delete the module-info.java to make the project a non-modular Java project.

Answer (score 1):

Seems a "*modul-info.java" related*" topic.

Suggestion:

- Restart Ecclipse and/or delete projects
- Create a new project and when creating a new project do NOT select "module-info.java"
- Create a package e.g. hellloworld (package.de.helloworld.chapter01)
- In this package right click and create a java class (here HelloWorld)
- Run this project as Java application

this should work.

You need also the main statement, you included this? :-)

```
package de.helloworld.chapter01;

public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
            
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had class in default package. I deleted the class and moved it in to a new package. That fixed problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps solved it for me;

1. Right-click on your project and select 'Properties' at the bottom.
2. Select 'Java Build Path' and navigate to the 'Libraries' tab. Remove
   existing libraries.
3. Add a new library by clicking on 'Add Library' from the menu on the right.
   Select 'JRE System Library' and click 'Next'.
4. Under 'System Library' select 'Execution Environment' and click
   'Finish'. Apply all changes & close.
5. Run your program now.